# Are there any writings that support the belief that Judas might be in Heaven now?

Tags: catholicism, hell, judas-iscariot

There is an article coming from Archbishop  Paglia, saying, **"For Catholics, who say that Judas is in hell, is a heresy."**

[Vatican Official: It’s Heresy to say Judas is in Hell](https://www.churchmilitant.com/news/article/vatican-official-claims-its-heresy-to-say-judas-in-hell)

When Ab. Paglia stated **"hell"** it means the **"real hell of the damned"**, the question is, was Judas really a damned soul and deserve to be put in real hell of the damned? Remember, when Judas died, he was not cast out in real hell of the damned but only in Hades or hell, a prison.

Further reading of scriptures, we know that the Catholic Church teaches in **Catechism (CCC 632k-635)**, that Jesus descended into hell/Hades to preach the gospel. Contemplating the passages, we will see, that Judas encounter Jesus in hell or Hades. The next important question is, if we place ourselves in the shoes of Judas, will we approach Jesus to ask for forgiveness, for betraying him?

Judas certainly repented in **Matthew 27:3-4**, with perfect contrition, as he first acknowledge his sins, regretted his sins, and return the money, completing the acts of perfect contrition.

> Then Judas, his betrayer, seeing that Jesus had been condemned, deeply regretted what he had done. He returned the thirty pieces of silver* to the chief priests and elders,

> saying, “I have sinned in betraying innocent blood.” They said, “What is that to us? Look to it yourself.”

Jesus descended into hell where Judas was cast out, to preach the gospel and to offer God's mercy, on all souls including Judas.

Did Jesus have a saving plan for Judas, why? Because, Jesus was the one who pushes Judas to commit the sins of betrayal, how?

Jesus said to Judas,

> What you are going to do, do quickly." (John 13:27)

If Jesus commanded Judas to commit the sins of betrayal, knowing Judas will forever be torture in eternal hell, that would present a Jesus contradicting the Will of the Father, as the Father sent Jesus not to condemn but to save souls in John 3:17, and the Father desires all men be saved in 1 Timothy 2:4.

If Jesus has no saving plan for Judas knowing he will be cast out into hell, then Jesus will contradict His very own words, as He said, **"I lay down my life for my friends"**, and Judas was a friend of Jesus, even after his betrayal.

On the night of his arrest, Jesus called Judas **"friend"** despite of his acts of betrayal, and so, Jesus lay down His life also to save Judas, because He still a friend of Jesus.

And for the second time, Jesus again commanded Judas to execute his plan of betrayal with a kiss.

> Jesus responded by saying: "Friend, do what you are here to do." - Matthew 26:50

We can see that twice, Jesus commanded Judas to fulfill and execute his plan of betrayal, wouldn't this be inappropriate if Jesus could no longer save Judas, as it appears that Judas was condemn to hell because Jesus pushes him to do it, not just once but twice.

Jesus could have said in the Last Supper,   *"Judas I know your betrayal plan for me, you are my friend, and I don't want you to suffer the eternal fire in hell, please stay here, do not execute your betrayal, because if you do so, then I can no longer save you in hell..."*

In view of the meditation or pondering of Judas fate and Jesus commands to Judas, is there any article supporting the minor view that Judas is in Heaven, because if the Catholic Church saw that anyone who say Judas is in hell, is a heresy, then, definitely, there's only one way for Judas, either he will be purge in purgatory after he accepted God's mercy offered by Jesus in hell, and it's over 2000 years now, Judas might have finish the purging now, and there's only one way up, but to Heaven.

Judas is in Heaven now, because Jesus has a saving plan for him, that is in line with the Will of the Father, desiring all men be saved. And Jesus clearly said,

> I have come not to do my own will but the Will of the Father who sent me. (John 6:38)

**Is there any article written, seeing Judas is in Heaven now?**

Comment: Scripture does not say where Judas went when he killed himself. Only that he went to 'his place' Acts 1:25. God shall judge, accordingly, in the resurrection.

Comment: @NigelJ Did Judas committed suicide with full consent? Remember, Satan entered Judas, and if you are familiar with Exorcism Rites, what do you think Satan will do, if he luckily entered a soul? Will Satan push one to commit suicide against his/her will?

Answer (score 3):

**Is there any writings that supported some beliefs that Judas might be in Heaven now?**

There is no Catholic Church Father or Doctor of the Church who wrote that Judas Iscariot was thought to be saved.

> The Son of man indeed goeth, as it is written of him: but woe to that man by whom the Son of man shall be betrayed: it were better for him, if that man had not been born. - [Matthew 26:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Matthew%2026%3A24)

Even if [Archbishop Paglia says it is heresy to say Judas is in hell](https://catholicism.org/archbishop-paglia-says-its-heresy-to-say-judas-is-in-hell.html), he is speaking on his own behalf and is clearly going against the traditions of the Church in this subject matter.

> Archbishop Vincenzo Paglia contradicts the tradition of the Church.
>
> Faithful Catholics are criticizing his comment, recalling how Our Lord spoke of Judas: "The Son of Man indeed goes, as it is written of him: but woe to that man by whom the Son of Man shall be betrayed. It were better for him, if that man had not been born."

Many saints and Catholic scholars have placed Judas in hell.

None have placed him in heaven.

Judas may have expressed sorrow for his actions in Matthew 27:3-4, but this did not involve any perfect contrition. For after returning the 30 pieces of silver he committed suicide out of despair.

The Sacred Liturgy of Good Friday, according to the Tridentine Rite has very strong wording in regards to Judas Iscariot.

> The Catholic Church took no specific view concerning the damnation of Judas during Vatican II; speaking in generalities, that Council stated, "[We] must be constantly vigilant so that ... we may not be ordered to go into the eternal fire (cf. Mk. 25, 41) like wicked and slothful servants (cf. Mk. 25, 26), into the exterior darkness where 'there will be the weeping and the gnashing of teeth' (Mt. 22, 13 and 25, 30)." The Vatican only proclaims individuals' Eternal Salvation through the Canon of Saints. There is no 'Canon of the Damned.'
>
> Also, the Decree of Justification, promulgated during Session VI of the Council of Trent, states in Cannon 6, "If anyone shall say that it is not in the power of man to make his ways evil, but that God produces evil as well as the good works, not only by permission, but also properly and of Himself, so that the betrayal of Judas is not less His own proper work than the vocation of Paul; let him be anathema." Here, the Council is making it clear that Judas exercised his own free will to commit the betrayal of Jesus Christ, rather than being predestined by God. Also, by contrasting the actions of Judas to those of Paul, the implication is that Judas is the opposite of a saint (i.e., damned).
>
> Liturgical institutions are part of the expressions of Sacred Tradition of the Catholic Church. Within the 1962 Roman Missal for the Tridentine Latin Mass, the Collect for Holy Thursday states: **"O God, from whom Judas received the punishment of his guilt, and the thief the reward of his confession ... our Lord Jesus Christ gave to each a different recompense according to his merits..."** In his commentary on the Liturgical Year, Abbot Gueranger, O.S.B. states that the Collect reminds Catholics that both Judas and the good thief are guilty, "...and yet, the one is condemned, the other pardoned." Thus, the Tridentine Latin Mass, as currently celebrated, continues to foster the tradition within the Catholic Church that Judas was punished. - [Judas Iscariot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot)

Amongst the numerous stained glass images in the [Church of St. John Baptist](http://www.yeovilhistory.info/stjohn.htm), Yeovil, England, there is one that depicts Judas Iscariot with a black halo!

[image]

In the Church of St John the Baptist, Yeovil, one stained glass window depicts Judas with a black halo.

Wonder if this could possibly allude to his being amongst the reprobates in Hell?

[image]

> Surrounded by a radiant halo, Jesus is depicted with His Apostles at the Last Supper. What makes this work unique among stained glass pictures of the Last Supper is that the traitorous Judas is shown with a black halo, perhaps a symbol of the evil betrayal. - [The Last Supper and Judas](https://www.stainedglassinc.com/window/3683-the-last-supper-and-judas/)

As I have already said there no Church writings that support some beliefs that Judas might be in Heaven right now. But there are some that seem to hold out hope for a Judas, but they fall short of stating he is in heaven.

> There are some apparent exceptions, especially within the Eastern tradition. Origen in his commentary on Matthew holds out hope for a Judas who was so filled with remorse that he impulsively wanted to precede Our Lord in death so as to be able to encounter him in his “naked soul” and beg for pardon. St. Gregory of Nyssa tends toward a hopeful opinion; St. Silouan of Athos says we should pray for his salvation even now.
>
> Pope Benedict had this to say of Judas:
>
> > The choice [of Our Lord in making Judas an apostle and companion] darkens the mystery around his eternal fate, knowing that Judas “repented and brought back the thirty pieces of silver to the chief priests and the elders, saying, ‘I have sinned in betraying innocent blood’” (Matt. 27:3-4). Even though he went to hang himself (cf. Matt. 27: 5), it is not up to us to judge his gesture, substituting ourselves for the infinitely merciful and just God.
>
> > The mystery of the Lord’s choice remains, all the more since Jesus pronounces a very severe judgement on him: “Woe to that man by whom the Son of man is betrayed!” (Matt. 26:24). - [Is Judas in Hell?](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/is-judas-in-hell)

Comment: Did Judas profess his faith that Jesus is the "Son of Man"? The answer is a Big No!. Therefore, how can Judas be the Son of Perdition, when he clearly did not betray Jesus as the "son of Man". Remember, in all the gospel passages, Judas look upon Jesus as "Rabbi" only. While Peter and the Apostles profess their faith, calling Jesus, "Master and Lord". Was Judas the Son of Perdition? Again, the gospel says NO!

Answer (score 3):

The Catholic Church has not officially declared that Judas is in heaven. In fact, the Church has consistently taught that Judas is in hell. The Catechism of the Catholic Church, which is the official summary of Catholic doctrine, states that Judas "by his own choice" went to "eternal damnation," (CCC 1033).

While it is true that Judas repented of his sin, the Catholic Church teaches that repentance alone is not enough to obtain salvation. One must also have faith in Jesus Christ, receive baptism, and persevere in a life of grace until the end (CCC 1257, 1987-2010).

In addition, the fact that Jesus called Judas "friend" does not necessarily mean that he was saved. Jesus also said that not everyone who calls him "Lord" will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only those who do the will of his Father (Matthew 7:21).

Therefore, while it is possible to speculate about the fate of Judas, based on various scriptural passages, it is not appropriate to make definitive statements about his salvation or damnation. The Catholic Church teaches that only God knows the hearts of men and that it is not for us to judge the eternal destiny of any soul.

Comment: After Judas committed suicide, he definitely cast out into hell or Hades, but not in the real hell of the damned. Remember, Jesus also descended into hell to preach the gospel and to offer the infinite mercy of God. Do you think Judas will accept the mercy of God? And ofcourse, Judas seeing Jesus alive, his faith will now change, he will realize that Jesus was not only "Rabbi" but indeed the Messiah and the Son of Man. If you were Judas suffering torments, will you seek forgiveness, and accept the mercy of God offered by Jesus in hell?

Answer (score 1):

The son of perdition at John 17:12, "While I was with them, I was keeping them in Thy name which Thou hast given Me; and I guarded them and not one of them perished "BUT" the son of perdition, that Scripture might be fulfilled." What Scripture? Psalm 41:9-10, "Even my closest friend in whom I trusted, Who ate my bread, Has lifted up his head against me."

That word "BUT" means that what follows is going to be the antithesis of what preceded it. It serves, therefore, to mark opposition, antithesis, or transition.

Judas is called "the son of perdition" because he became the product of that which brings ruin. The Greek words translated "lost" and "perdition have the same basic meaning except the first is a verb and the second is a noun. The word means "to suffer utter loss/utter destruction."

Comment: Judas is not the Son of Perdition, if Peter did not rise up, he perfectly fits the Son of Perdition, as he boldly profess his faith that Jesus was the Messiah, the Son of the Living God, the Son of Man and his Master and Lord. The other Apostles also qualifies as the Son of Perdition but not Judas, who lacks faith in Jesus as the Son of Man, as he look upon Jesus as "Rabbi" only, I repeat "Rabbi" only. So, Judas did not betray Jesus as the "Son of Man" and Judas is not the Son of Perdition.

Comment: @jongricafo So your telling me that I'm misreading the  words of Jesus Christ Himself at John 17:12, "While I was with them, I was keeping them in Thy name which Thou hast given Me; and I guarded them, and not one of them perished "BUT" THE SON OF PERDITION that the Scripture might be fulfilled." If Peter fits the bill as you say why did Jesus at Matthew 16:17 say Peter was blessed because he knew that Jesus was the Christ, the Son of the living God? Also, does it sound like Peter is the son of perdition when ask the Roman Emperor to crucify him upside down? Is this eternal destruction to you?

Comment: Mr.Bond, who fits the bill in this passage, "Even my closest friend in whom I trusted, Who ate my bread, Has lifted up his head against me.", Did Judas lifted up his head against Jesus? This is more of a prophecy for all the Bishops, who will be infected by the spirit of Antichrist or Antigospel or Antimercy, who will lift up their proud head against the Vicar of Christ. The Modern Day Judas Bishops, who betrays their oath of fidelity and obedience to Pope Francis, are the true "Son of Perdition" today, as they will lead their followers to eternal damnation.

Comment: @jongricafort I'm not interested in going into a "tangent" regarding Bishops, Popes or antichrist. We are not talking about "THE" antichrist/son of perdition at 2 Thessalonians 2:3. The issue at hand is who betrayed Jesus Christ. I say it was Judas and you say it was Peter, at least that's what I understood you to say. Now, If you would read Matthew 26:20-25 you will see at vs25, "And Judas, who was betraying Him etc. He's the son of perdition without question. In fact at Mark 14:21 Jesus says, "It would have been good for that man if he had not been born."

Comment: The four gospel never stated that Judas profess his faith that Jesus is the "Son of Man", Judas only look upon Jesus as "Rabbi", so how can Judas betrays Jesus as the Son of Man?

Answer (score 1):

The OP implies that the Archbishop in question taught that Judas is in heaven. But the linked article does not state this. Rather the Archbishop claimed it is heresy to teach that Judas is in Hell. For Catholics there is a third alternative, namely Purgatory.

We should also be aware that the issue that the Archbishop was addressing here was not Judas' betrayal of Jesus, but his suicide. On that matter, the Catholic Church has indeed issued written statements to the effect that [suicide does not necessarily result in the utter damnation of the soul](https://www.tennessean.com/story/news/religion/2018/12/15/catholic-suicide-don-lacuesta-sin-teaching/2322335002/).

> The Catechism states that "we are stewards, not owners, of the life
> God has entrusted to us. It is not ours to dispose of." But it goes on
> to state that "grave psychological disturbances, anguish, or grave
> fear of hardship, suffering, or torture can diminish the
> responsibility of the one committing suicide," seemingly making an
> exception for mental illness or other mitigating factors that might
> lead a person to end their life.

**Souls in Purgatory may eventually advance to Heaven, so it is not out of the question that Judas would attain that state. However, there is no official teaching to that effect. On the other hand, there are indeed written statements from the Church to the effect that suicide does not necessarily condemn a soul the Hell forever.**

Comment: The important question is, did Judas committed suicide on his own, or since Satan entered his soul, Judas action was not his own, but it was influence by Satan.

Answer (score -2):

**Is there any writings that supported some beliefs that Judas might be in Heaven now?**

Before I answer this question, let me address first, the people who thinks Judas is the "Son of Perdition".

If Judas was the Son of Perdition for his betrayal, then Judas can blame Jesus for the fulfillment of his betrayal, how?

Jesus committed three mistakes, if Judas is the Son of Perdition, how?

1. Jesus gave Judas the eucharist, eventhough He knew the state of soul of Judas, he was in the **"state of sin"**, and worst, Judas did not believe in the **"real presence**" and so, Jesus allowed Judas to commit the sin of sacrilege, and it gave Satan an access to Judas soul.
2. Jesus commanded Judas to fulfill his plan of betrayal saying,

> "What your going to do, do quickly." - John 13:27

*Jesus could have said, Judas, I knew you plan to betray me, but please, stay here, because if you do so, you will be forever cast into hell, and I can no longer save you. I am your friend, and I don't want to see you tormented in hell.*

3. Jesus on the night of His arrest, still called Judas his **"friend"** despite the action of Judas on Him, Jesus still love Judas as His friend, nothing change. But, we knew, what happened in scriptures, Jesus once again commanded Judas, instead of stopping him from his plan of betrayal. Jesus said...

> Jesus responded by saying: "Friend, do what you are here to do." - Matthew 26:50

If we believe that Judas is the **"Son of Perdition"**, then reading the scriptures, will lead us to Jesus as the culprit, because if Jesus was the true friend of Judas, He won't allow Judas to suffer or be tormented in hell, by His commands to Judas, to do quickly and accomplish his plan of betrayal. Jesus pushes Judas to hell.

But ofcourse, a deep pondering, we can see that, although Jesus commanded Judas and gave the eucharist to him, it was all allowed by Divine Providence, because Jesus knew, He can save Judas even in hell.

**Pondering deeply the scriptures...**

- *Judas was cast into hell after committing suicide against his will, because Satan entered his soul, to seek his destruction.*
- *Jesus descended into Hell, and since, He lay down His life for His friends, will definitely look for Judas, to offer God's mercy upon him, and Judas since, he already made a perfect contrition, will definitely seek forgiveness, and seeing that Jesus was indeed the Messiah, his faith on Jesus is now clear, Jesus is truly the "Son of Man".*
- *Judas will say to Jesus, "Master and Lord, you are indeed the Messiah, the Son of Man, please forgive me..." And Jesus will answer, "I forgive you Judas, endure the purging, and one day you will be with me in Heaven..."*

With regards to article describing the good side of Judas as our brother in Christ, here is a fine article, for us to ponder who Judas really is, in the eyes of Jesus Christ.

[Our Brother Judas](https://wherepeteris.com/judas-our-brother/)

Judas fallen life, had preach the evil betraying Jesus and the evil of committing suicide, and that was his great contribution to the Church, to warn all souls not to commit it.

**Judas is our Brother, and most probably even certainly, Judas is in Heaven now.**